# How can I show Fourier transform with given function

Tags: fourier-transform

Given

$$F\{\mu\} = \int f(t)e^{-j2\pi\mu t} dt $$

Show that

$$F\{f(t \pm t0)\} = e^{\pm j2\pi \mu t_0}F\{\mu\}$$

Do I have to solve this by using this formula?

$$\int f(t)e^{−j2!μt}dt =\int f(t)[cos(2\pi\mu t) − jsin(2\pi\mu t)]dt$$

Is there any easier way to prove this problem?

Comment: What do you get from $ \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-j2\pi\mu t} dt$ with the change of variable $t = t'+a$ ?

Comment: You mean at the second function?

Comment: No I meant what I wrote.

Comment: maybe this? $$\int f(t')[cos(2\pi\mu t') − jsin(2\pi\mu t')]dt * \int f(a)[cos(2\pi\mu a) − jsin(2\pi\mu a)]dt$$ is it right?

Comment: No, this is not correct. And I told you to apply the change of variable to $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t)e^{-j2\pi\mu t} dt$

Comment: Do you know that $\int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t) dt = \int_{-\infty}^\infty g(t+a) dt $ ?

Comment: oh without using formula, then i get $$\int f(t'+a)e^{-j2\pi\mu (t'+a)}dt$$ I still dont understand the big F on the last part of 2nd function

Comment: answer of your question is just above is that wrong? and mine? I still dont know :(... little bit more hint?

Comment: $\int f(t'+a)e^{-j2\pi\mu (t'+a)}dt$ is what I wanted. Then $e^{u+v} = e^u e^b$ ..

Comment: um so I can get $$ \int f(t'+a)e^{j2\pi \mu t}*e^{j2\pi \mu a}dt$$

Comment: You meant $$e^{-j2\pi \mu a}\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t'+a)e^{-j2\pi \mu t'}dt'$$ Please write the bounds carefully. It is not a primitive but an integral from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.

Comment: um isn't  $$e^{-j2\pi\mu a}$$ still has to the inside of integral? And Yes the domain is from -inf to +inf I dont know how to represent that in this website :( sorry

Comment: $e^{-j2\pi\mu a}$ is a constant since we integrate with respect to $t$ (or $t'$)

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhh I see the $$e^{-j2\pi \mu a}$$ is the constant, I get it. Oh and the dt has to be changed to dt'

Comment: oh so the answer is that since I have constant at the front and $$F\{\mu\}$$ is same as $$F\{f(t)\}$$ So $$F\{f(t \pm t0)\} = e^{\pm j2\pi \mu t_0}F\{\mu\}$$ is right! Am I right?

Comment: The notation is confusing. In general we write $\mathcal{F}\{ f(t) \}(\mu) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(t) e^{-2i \pi \mu t} dt$

Comment: oh well, What I can see in my note is just $$F\{\mu\}$$ and the rest of them is same. maybe I wrote the wrong one :(